# How to sum static value in each count in for loop or in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my code which show how many days left:

```
 <?php

 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime("11/19/2017");
 $datediff =  $your_date-$now;

 $jam=  round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

 ?>
 <p class="counter-number"><?=$jam?></p>
```

just imagine if difference between days are 10. then i want to run this in counter means

```
1st day :- 6 * 5 = 30
2nd day :- 6 * 5 + 30 = 60
3rd day :- 6 * 5 + 60 = 90
```

and then so on to 10 days then sum all.

Please help me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _count in for loop or in while loop.._ Where is your loop? I don't see any loops here...

Comment: whats this mean `in counter means`

Comment: Hello @B001Thanks for getting help me for this. kindly i think that my issue is solved from (count in for loop or in while loop) but i didn't know how to solve my issue. please help me to solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're using google translate, but it's very hard to understand your question :(

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
$day = 0;
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
   $day += 6 * 5;
   $sum += $day;
   echo "Day $i = $day\n";
   echo "Sum $sum\n\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
Day 0 = 30
Sum 30

Day 1 = 60
Sum 90

Day 2 = 90
Sum 180

Day 3 = 120
Sum 300

Day 4 = 150
Sum 450

Day 5 = 180
Sum 630

Day 6 = 210
Sum 840

Day 7 = 240
Sum 1080

Day 8 = 270
Sum 1350

Day 9 = 300
Sum 1650
```

You can try it here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/910edb9e0aef99893c438a29e52b5cb51bdb32c3

The `+=` basically means  `$var += 5` is same as `$var = $var + 5`  so when in a loop it takes the previous value and increments it by `x` amount.

So for example loop 1

```
6 * 5 = 30
6 * 5 + 30 = 60
6 * 5 + 60 = 90
```

OR

```
6 * 5 = $x
6 * 5 + $x = $x
6 * 5 + $x + $x = $x
```

etc...  So on each loop we add one more `$x`

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your great code ArtisticPhoenix but how i implement this on day count. means 

    1st day :- 6 * 5 = 30
    2nd day :- 6 * 5 + 30 = 60
    3rd day :- 6 * 5 + 60 = 90

Comment: Hello ArtisticPhoenix do you know how to do this on days wise.
 1st day :- 6 * 5 = 30 2nd day :- 6 * 5 + 30 = 60 3rd day :- 6 * 5 + 60 = 90
Thanks

Comment: Hello ArtisticPhoenix Thanks alot for your great code. but i want this loop run day by day. Hope you understand in my code i did today date and expiry date difference. and then i want each day run loop query. automatically. Thanks

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Please check my latest comment

Comment: how would I know that when the value of `"$mydate"` is undefined.

Comment: no $mydate is not undefined in this database date is (12/17/2017)

Comment: How should I know that based on your question, am I psychic?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Please check my question code i edit it now.

Comment: So how does `43` the answer  to what you have for the date diffrence relate to the rest?  Please see your code in test sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88159f343b2f991f7e3a60525946b9284ce46db6

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix 43 means ??

Comment: `$ja = 43` is the output of your code.  And that relates to the rest How?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You are great every moment you help me for this. please check the code of (geeth) just down me he little bit near to my issue. hope you help me now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following algorithm (in pseudo-code):

```
$i=1;
$total=0;
while ($i <= 10)
{
   $total = $total + (6*5*$i);
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hello Ab Bennett Thanks for your answer will you please tell me how i make  proper code with my upper code. Thanks it's hard to take this. Thanks

Comment: how so, my loop starts at 1. i figured from reading the question by day 10 he wanted (30+60+90..+300).      "and then so on to 10 days then sum all."

Comment: because, on loop 1 you have `30`, next loop you have  `30 + 30 * 2`, then `90 + 30 * 3 `.. etc.  by the 10th your around `1600`

Comment: yeh, way i read his question is this is what he wanted "    and then so on to 10 days then sum all.
" i think the requirement was lost in translation

Comment: `1650` which is about 4.5 years.

Comment: this is the way the question reads, it says "then sum all". @geeth has the exact same interpretation

Comment: I think the OP wants both the Sum and the Days,  so we were both wrong ... lol ... hard to understand.

Comment: Hello Ab Bannett  do you know how to do this on days wise. 
1st day :- 6 * 5 = 30
 2nd day :- 6 * 5 + 30 = 60 
3rd day :- 6 * 5 + 60 = 90 
Thanks

Comment: just simple maths x = days * 5 * 6

Comment: One way without a loop is just 10 * 11 / 2 * 5 * 6 = 1650.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you are looking for this, because your question is little bit confusing.

```
 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime("$mydate");
 $datediff =  $your_date-$now;

 $jam=  round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

 $sum = 0;
 for($i = 0; $i < $jam; $i++){
    $sum += 6 * 5 + (30 * $i);
 }
 echo $sum;
```

change the value of $i in condition with proper variable

Comment: Hello geeth Thanks for your answer will you please tell me how i make  proper code with my upper code. Thanks it's hard to take this. Thanks

Comment: you just near my question :) please help me to solve my issue :)

Comment: first of all, make your question clear. i have answered from my understanding